# how can I select rows that column does NOT have more than 1 value?

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and I am wondering how to solve this issue. For example, my table looks as follows:

[image: My Initial table example]

As you see in the table `item_id` 1 appears in both `city_id` 1 and 2, so does the `item_id` 4, but I want to get all the items where appears only in one `city_id`.
In this example, these would be `item_id` 2 (appearing only in `city_id` 2) and `item_id` 3 (appearing in `city_id` 1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY item_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT city_id) = 1
```

In case you want to see the `city_id` to you can use this query:

```
SELECT item_id, MIN(city_id) AS city_id
FROM example 
GROUP BY item_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT city_id) = 1
```

Since there is only one `city_id` you can use `MIN` or `MAX` to get the id.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36de45b649d3fc417b704a6fb4ba3b16)

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation on `item_id` and count *distinct* values of `city_id`. The `having` clause can be used to filter on aggregates.

```
select item_id from mytable group by id having count(distinct city_id) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all the id where they have only one distinct city:

```
 SELECT item_id
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY item_id 
 HAVING count(distinct city_id) = 1
```

It works by counting all the different values that city_id has for the same item_id. For those item ids where they repeat a lot, but the city_id is always the same the count of unique values in the city id is 1, and we can look for these using a HAVING clause. "Having" is like a where clause that runs after a GROUP BY operation is completed. It is the conceptual equivalent of this:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM
(
 SELECT item_id, count(distinct city_id) as cdci 
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY item_id
) x
WHERE cdci = 1
```

If you want the city id too you can either get the MAX city (because in this case there is only one city so it's safe to do):

```
 SELECT item_id, MAX(city_id) as city_id
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY item_id 
 HAVING count(distinct city_id) = 1
```

or you could join this query back to the item table as a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
(
 SELECT item_id
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY item_id 
 HAVING count(distinct city_id) = 1
) x
INNER JOIN 
table t
ON x.item_id = t.item_id
```

This technique is the more general process for performing a group by that finds some particular set of rows, then bringing in the rest of the data from that row. You cant always stick every other column you want in a MAX because it will mix row data up, and you can't put the extra columns in your group by because that will subdivide what you're grouping on, giving the wrong results. Doing the group as a subquery and joining it back is a typical way to get all the row data when you have to group it to find which rows are interesting

In your case this form of query will bring all the duplicated rows (whereas the group by/max won't). If you don't want the duplicate rows you can make the top line `SELECT DISTINCT t.*` but don't make a habit of slapping distinct in to get rid of duplicated rows; if your tables don't have duplicates to start with but suddenly after you wrote a JOIN you got duplicated rows, google fornwhat a Cartesian product is in database queries and how to prevent it

Comment: I wonder if this much detailing is required for the above query

Comment: Hang on while I check if SO changed it's tagline to "StackOverflow; where newbies come to get code only answers with no surrounding explanation so they can understand what's going on"...

Comment: Nope, it's still "StackOverflow; ... where developers learn, share their knowledge and build ..."

Answer (score 0):

You just need a group by on item id with having

```
 Select item_id from table group by 
  item_id having count(distinct city_id) 
   =1
```

Also, if you want to have majority of same no of rows as input then

```
  Select item_id, city, rank() 
    over(partition by item_id order by city) 
    rn 
   From table where rn=1;
```